# htaccess rewrite and redirect URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i'm looking for a htaccess rule that can do this:

**Original URL:** `?til=main`
**Replace to:** `/main`

and if this is the scenario:

**Original URL:** `/index.php?til=main` or `?til=main`
**Redirect to:** `/main`

Till now i only have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?til=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It loads `/main` but behind it loads `/index.php?til=main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?til=(.*)\ HTTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?til=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?til=$1 [L]
```

It should redirect `index.php?til=main` and `?til=main` to `/main`

Comment: how can i replace til=main for something like til=%1 ??

Comment: yep it works! ... quick question is there any problem if i use it like this: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)?til=([^&\ ]+)\ HTTP RewriteRule ^ /folder/%2? [R=301,L]` it seems to work fine with both index.php?til=xxxx and ?til=xxxx

Comment: @Ered `(.*)` It matches any character (except line breaks) which appears zero or more time on first capturing group (which you can refer with `$1`). While the latter `([^&\ ]+)` matches any character except &, \ and spaces with one or more time on second capturing group which referred with `$2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)\?til=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?til=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it's not redirecting if i go to index.php?til=main or ?til=main